# How to completely remove network-manager

Tags: gnome, 18.04, network-manager

A few days ago, my computer WiFi was getting interrupted. Because of this, I connected the modem directly to the computer. But I still had a problem connecting to the Internet, and sometimes my connection to the Internet was interrupted. So I decided to remove the Gnome Network Manager and install WICD instead. Currently, my connection problem is fixed, but Ubuntu sometimes install Gnome Network Manager and I have the same problem again. How can I prevent Ubuntu from installing the Gnome Network Manager?
Here are the commands that I use to remove Gnome Network Manager.

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo dpkg --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

I run the last command after installing WICD and rebooting.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, That solved my problem now. I'll accept duplication if the problem does not appear again.